# Cloning a reference type

Tags: c#

Consider the following

I have an Html Template object

```
   class HtmlTemplateModel
    {
       public HTML Html {get;set;}
       //..etc
    }
```

and an Html Editor

```
class HtmlEditorViewModel
{
   private HtmlTemplateModel htmlTemplateModel;
   public HtmlEditor(HtmlTemplateModel htmlTemplateModel)
   {
      this.htmlTemplateModel = htmlTemplateModel;
   }
}
```

This way the TemplateEditor instance applies the changes to the original template since its a reference type, but i dont want to modify its value so i made a new constructor that takes an `HtmlTemplateModel` and creates a new `HtmlTemplateModel`.

- is this the best way to clone reference type in .NET?
- and is there a shortcut so that i don't have to create another
  constructor to clone the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to serialize the object, it will make a deep copy of the source object.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23832/Implementing-Deep-Cloning-via-Serializing-objects