# none static nested class inside static class c#

Tags: c#, static

consider this scenario

```
Public static Class GlobalParam
{
//static classes strings int and more...
  class NoneStaticClass
  {
    //some noneStatic params
  }
}
```

in another `class` ( none static ) I call for an instance of `NoneStaticClass` in this fashion

```
GlobalParam.noneStaticClass NSC = new GlobalParam.noneStaticClass();

//some manipulation on NSC params
```

Later I use Method Like that

```
void DoSomething(GlobalParam.noneStaticClass nsc)
{
  GlobalParam.noneStaticClass NewNSC = nsc 
  //Some manipulation in NewNSC 
}
```

now when I check the data stored in NSC I can clearly that it has been changed , why is that ? 
does putting none static class inside a static is not correct in some way ?

Comment: I think this question is entirely unrelated to static-ness. This is about references to instances vs. deep copying of instances.

Comment: Can you make your example more clear? That is, include a simple program that shows the whole flow of logic? It's not entirely clear what you're doing here (e.g. are you passing `NSC`  as a parameter to `DoSomething()`?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve, as I think the method your trying is not suitable to the problem

Comment: Looks like you're just passing around the same instance of NoneStaticClass. Naming the variable `NewNSC` in that method doesn't make it a new one.

Comment: ... or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696448/how-to-make-a-copy-of-an-object-in-c-sharp) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843958/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-reference-type) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698361/cloning-a-reference-type) ...

Comment: Nesting classes is almost never a good idea. And the nesting and static are unrelated to the core of your question.

Comment: Thank you all and you probably right that it is a dup , but I've never encountered this problem before , and now  I can tell it is wrong !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever your class is nested or normal class, whenever you do an assignement like  `GlobalParam.noneStaticClass NewNSC = nsc`, `NewNSC` and `nsc` will always reference the same object.

If you want a copy of your nsc object, here are some ways to do it :

- If your class has all members with value type, you can use a struct
  instead of class. It will be copied each time you make an assignment
  with.
- If not, you should referer to object [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Comment: yes without some `Clone()` like call, no hope

Answer (score 1):

This is because your are not creating a new instance of the class when you write `GlobalParam.noneStaticClass NewNSC = nsc` you are merely assigning a reference to the existing `NSC` object to the new variable `NewNSC`. Therefore when you call `NewNSC` you are calling the same object as `NSC`.

In order to create a new instance of the object you would need to do this:

`GlobalParam.noneStaticClass NewNSC = new GlobalParam.noneStaticClass();`